# Android : Handle Navigation History For Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation, fragment, history

I am writing an android application where when user clicks on a item on navigation drawer, a new fragment is initiated to handle the use case respective to the click.

There are several entry or trigger points for one fragment.
Eg : List of posts is shown under various options; Recent Post List , Top Post List , Category Post List.
From these fragments, when user clicks on a post; the selected post is opened.

Now, I need to handle "back" button click here. As of now, clicking back exits the application. If I add `"addToBackStack"` calls during fragments; it does not function in the desired manner and traversal history is not maintained.

I can post code snippets if required but for now i wanted to know where i am wrong and what is the solution i can try. Looking forward to core concept associated here.

Added Code Snippet : 
`fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("home");` 
`fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment);`

Comment: You are using `.add` or `.replace`? Can you post the fragment transaction code?

Comment: Updated Initial Post

Answer (score 0):

Implementing the `onBackPressed` method of activity solved the problem.
I tracked the navigation in a global `Stack` and then handled the stack and invoked specific fragments/activities depending on the navigation done by app user.
Custom history and back tracking for fragments worked best option for me.
 I think it works best especially when there are multiple entry points for one fragment from various others in the app.